# Ending array input (C++ industry-standards)

Tags: c++, arrays, user-input

The code I've written is working, but I feel like there's probably a better, and standard way to end the input of an array that I may not know about. The code in question is in the getInputForArray() and implemented by stopping the loop if cin.fail() is detected on integer input. Is there a better way? Thanks, all.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int sumOfArray(int arr[], int arrlen);
void getInputForArray(int arr[], int arrlen);

int main() {
    const int LIST_SZ = 256;
    int mylist[LIST_SZ];
    // Zero out the array
    for (int i = 0; i < LIST_SZ; i++)
        mylist[i] = 0;
    // Get user input for array
    getInputForArray(mylist, LIST_SZ);
    // Print the sum of all the numbers in the array
    cout << "\nThe sum is: " << sumOfArray(mylist, LIST_SZ) << endl;
    return 0;
}

int sumOfArray(int arr[], int arrlen) {
    int total = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < arrlen; i++)
        total = arr[i] + total;
    return total;
}

void getInputForArray(int arr[], int arrlen) {
    cout << "Input any non-numerical value to denote the end of your input\n";
    for (int i = 0; i < arrlen; i++) {
        if (!cin.fail()) {
            cout << "Please input a value for the [" << i
                 << "] position of the array: ";
            cin >> arr[i];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What if the user accidentally types non-numerical input but actually wishes to continue to enter data?

Comment: That's a good point that I was worried about, but I don't want to assign an integer value you can use to exit (i.e. type 0 to exit). Besides those two breaks, I'm not really sure how else to implement.

Comment: The C++ standard doesn't dictate how you design your applications. You can do it any way you want, any answer here would be entirely opinion-based. If you want help with user interaction, ux.stackexchange.com would be a better place to ask.

Comment: @Barmar: The OP is asking about standards as in best practices, not as in the ISO definition of the language.

Comment: @Barmar I meant 'standard practice'*. I'm not familiar with that site though, thanks, I'll check it out.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit OK, but best bractice questions are generally off-topic here, too, because they're primarily opinions.

Comment: @Barmar I don't see why industry-standards would not be an acceptable topic of stackoverflow.

Comment: Sometimes Ctrl+Z is used (end-of file symbol). However, I think anything you choose will be ok - as long as you tell user how they are expected to indicate the end of data.

Comment: @Boomer There are very few "industry standards" that are really standards. They're mostly just common practices, traditions, and style of the day.

Comment: @yu_sha Ctl-Z is used on Windows, the equivalent on Unix is Ctl-D. On Unix, typing Ctl-Z will suspend the application.

Comment: Ok, agree. Ctrl-Z, Ctrl-D or anything you wish, as long as user knows what it is.

Comment: You should post such questions to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Other answers addressed the EOF (or end of input) option.

OP can modify the user input checks to stop the loop when non numerical inputs are entered twice. I also consider a better practice to use a `std::vector` instead of a raw array.

This is a possible implementation:

```
std::vector<int> getDataFromInput( size_t max_data )
{
    using std::cout;

    std::vector<int> v;
    std::string value;

    bool stop_reading = false;

    while ( v.size() < max_data )
    {
        cout << "Please input a value for position [" << v.size() << "] of the vector: ";
        // input a string, if End of Input, stop reading
        if ( !(std::cin >> value) ) break;
        try
        {   // if the user entered a valid number, add it to the vector
            int num = stoi(value);
            v.push_back(num);
            stop_reading = false;
        }
        catch ( const std::invalid_argument &e )
        {
            if ( stop_reading ) break;
            cout << "You entered a non-numerical value.\nPlease, enter another "
                 << "non-numerical value to stop input or a number to continue\n";
            stop_reading = true;
        }
        catch ( const std::out_of_range &e )
        {
            cout << "The value entered can't be represented by an int.\n";
        }
    }

    return v;
}
```

**EDIT**

As [Lightness races in orbit](https://stackoverflow.com/users/560648/lightness-races-in-orbit) pointed out:

> It's more "industry standard" to stop input by sending EOF. You can
>   usually do that from terminal with ^D (Linux/Mac) or ^Z (Windows).

So you can simplify my previous snippet to this:

```
std::vector<int> getDataFromInput( size_t max_data )
{
    using std::cout;

    std::vector<int> v;
    std::string value;

    while ( v.size() < max_data )
    {
        cout << "Please input a value for position [" << v.size()
             << "] of the vector: ";
        if ( !(std::cin >> value) ) break;
        try
        {
            int num = stoi(value);
            v.push_back(num);
        }
        catch ( const std::invalid_argument &e )
        {
            cout << "You entered a non-numerical value.\n";
        }
        catch ( const std::out_of_range &e )
        {
            cout << "The value entered can't be represented by an int.\n";
        }
    }

    return v;
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure if you're the same person that submitted the first comment about using vectors instead of arrays, but the `std::istream_iterator<int>(std::cin), std::istream_iterator<int>());` being returned as a vector was exactly like what I was looking for. This comment about checking inputs on the vectors also helps a lot.

Comment: @Boomer no, there was another answer, now deleted, which used the istream iterators to initialize the vector.

Comment: I realize that now. But your answer in conjunction with the other solved my dilemma, and your answer is very detailed. Thank you.

Comment: It's more "industry standard" to stop input by sending EOF. You can usually do that from terminal with ^D (Linux/Mac) or ^Z (Windows). Your code already supports that, so it's just a case of removing the `stop_reading` variable, thereby simplifying your program somewhat.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit there was another answer (now deleted) that did that. My main point is that as the user input should be always checked, adding a sort of "Are you sure you want to quit?" option may be cheap and (it seems to me) quite common for user interaction. I'm afraid that what could be considered an "industry standard" for this task is quite opinion (and/or experience) based.

Comment: @Bob__: Yes, I saw that answer. I don't know why it was deleted. I voted to undelete it. As for "Are you sure you want to quit?", I'm not suggesting removing it, but fixing it. Quitting by entering two invalid inputs is .... weird. There's no strong semantics to it. Just let the user enter as many invalid inputs as they like, without quitting, and quit only with ^D/^Z (as your program does _already_)!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Well, I still think it depends on the level of user interaction needed by the application (or wanted by the developer) and on how dangerous the task is. I'd like to have a chance to reconsider my options after typing `format C:` (unless you are that sort of guy who thinks that stupidity must be punished), but I understand your point.

Comment: @Bob__: If you aren't sure what you're doing ("stupidity" as you put it), you should be using a friendly GUI overlay like Windows to format your hard disks. Those warn. Does the cmdline tool `format` warn? Don't think so. Don't want to try it though :)

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this.

```
void getInputForArray(int arr[], int arrlen) {
    char c = 0;
    size_t size = 0;
    cout << "Press escape (ESC) to stop inputting values" << endl;

    while(size < arrlen) {
        cout << "Enter a number for position " << size << " of the array: ";
        cin >> arr[size++];

        fflush(stdin);
        c = getchar();
        if(c == 27) { // check for the escape key
            break; // jump out of the loop
        }

        // Check non-numeric values.
        if(cin.fail()) {
            cout << "Error: numerical values only!" << endl;
            cin.clear(); // clear the input
            size--; // go back to previous position
        }
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you can check for EOF (End OF File) by changing the line `if(c == 27)` which checks for the escape key to `if(c == EOF)`. EOF is a macro because its value is system dependent. However, I don't recommend this alternative because the key sequence is different on each system. Ctrl+Z for DOS-based or CP/M systems, Ctrl+D for Unix-like systems, Ctrl+\ for AmigaOS, and possibly others.

Comment: Meh. All you've done is added _yet another_ key sequence. Nobody uses ESC to terminate input any more, and the key is usually associated with closing windows. Who knows what it'll do in someone's terminal window. I would _definitely_ recommend you stick with the typical EOF character for the platform in question. If your users don't already know what that is, then it's a good opportunity to educate. Furthermore, this won't conflict with natural EOF scenarios (input isn't always typed with a keyboard!). Beyond that, this is not at all idiomatic C++ with its use of C macros and the like.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I'm going to disagree with you about the ESC key.   It's often used to close dialog boxes, to stop loading (esp. browsers), exit full screen, or pause. Basically, it's a catch-all for *stop*. If you use EOF, you have to consider each system you deploy to because they use different control codes (End-Of-Transmission, Substitute, File Separator, etc). However, you're absolutely right about my solution being more C-like.

Comment: All of those examples are fundamentally different from signifying end of input. As I already alluded to in my first comment, they marry up more closely with terminating the program, or even closing the terminal window entirely. ESC for end of input would be very surprising. Please do name some console applications that use ESC for ending input, setting a UX precedent for this choice.